# I am unable to get tensorflow to execute

Tags: python-3.x

The following is a snippet from my Python 3.5 interpreter.  I don't understand why this produces the error (Listed bellow).  Any suggestions?

```
Python 3.5.3 (v3.5.3:1880cb95a742, Jan 16 2017, 16:02:32) [MSC v.1900 64
bit (AM
D64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> hello = tf.constant('Hello, Tensorflow!')
>>> sess = tf.Session()
>>> print(sess.run(hello))
```

Then it gives me just a list of internal Errors starting with:

```
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943]
```